# Link DB with html dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, database, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

Firstly I'm new to JavaScript programming. I have two drop down menus (month/year) and they have static values. I want to get value from database with `timestamp (year:xxxx month:xx)`. 
The SQL-statements are already defined, now I need to link both.

Comment: You need to make a GET or POST to the server side using javascript or jquery.

Comment: whatever you are using server side make a ajax call

Comment: Thx 4 the answer, but the connection to the server already works.

Comment: function init(){
    //Get Data
    var socket = io.connect('...');
    socket.emit('requested_lsc_1', { MONTH: 11, YEAR: 2014 }); // --> call to adapt with requested_lsc_1 and then parameters month = 11 and year = 2014
    socket.on('lsc_1', function(data){ 
     console.log(data);